# Progressbar not showing when using Theme.NoTitleBar

Tags: android, progress-bar, android-manifest, fullscreen

I want show my progress bar when loading my data and to make my activity full screen without a title bar.

I set my activity to be full screen by adding this to my manifest:

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
```

When I remove that theme on my manifest the progress bar is showing normally.

Any ideas to make my activity full screen **and** my progress bar show??

Thanks..

Please help me...

Answer (score 0):

Try `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoDisplay"`

Comment: it make not just my progressbar not showing,but all my layout not showing also.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using Theme.NoTitleBar.fullscreen, use this，have the same effect.

```
 <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">

    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorLightBlue</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorLightBlue</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
     <!-- use below. -->
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
   </style>
```